# Using the literal characters <> in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the command below which I have been trying to run using invoke-command on a remote server. I keep getting errors either  "<< was unexpected at this time." or "The system cannot find the file specified." I am guessing the issue has to do with the inner quotes and the <> characters which surround the password. I've tried putting a ` as an escape character before the single quotes and <> with no luck. What is the proper syntax for using the single quotes and literal <> characters?

```
Regular Command which runs fine - \bin\svc.exe -service='install,scv1,UserName <Pwd>,,,M'
```

Powershell command:

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceSrv -ScriptBlock { cmd.exe /c "$Using:SourcePath\Bin\svc.exe -service='install,svc1, $Using:SvcUser <$Using:SvcPwd>,,,M' " }
```

Comment: Why do you want `<>` if you don't have it in the command that works? Also: you don't need to  call cmd.exe, you can call executables directly from powershell. Last but not least: copy past the error would help. `<<` usually refers to a position that fails and has nothing to do with the `<` in your command.

Comment: cmd is likely seeing those characters as a redirection operators and trying to pull file content in for the previous command. You need to escape it from cmd not PowerShell pretty sure.

Comment: @Matt powershell or cmd might be removing the quotes, but it's hard to tell in such an overly complicated question.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Indeed. But trying to escape them from cmd might yeild some more information.

Comment: @vrdse I didn't realize the <> were interpreted as an html link in the post box. I've edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the parsers are removing your quotes and trying to interpret the `<>` command characters for file redirection.  You do not need to invoke `cmd.exe` to call an executable, you can do that natively from powershell (with the call operator `&`):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceSrv -ScriptBlock {
    & "$using:SourcePath\Bin\svc.exe" "-service='install,svc1, $using:SvcUser <$using:SvcPwd>,,,M'"
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Now when the parser is interpreting the <> characters and adding another on each side. How would i avoid this from happening? 

`-service='install,mucs, User <<password>>,,,M' '`

Comment: @soad122 Does your `$svcpwd` variable have those characters already?

Comment: no they in cmd as literals, i guess i could just make them part of the variable.

Comment: Try embedding the quotes: ``"`" ... `""``